# ce_count is count from kernel software or read from register of memory controller?

Tags: kernel, drivers, memory

The value in sysfile is count from OS or read from register of memory controller?

```
/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc*/ce_count
```

I see it is counting from OS, but I think the value should be counted by HW.

```
mci->csrows[row]->channels[chan]->ce_count += count;
```

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/08bf1a27c4c354b853fd81a79e953525bbcc8506/drivers/edac/edac_mc.c#L980

Comment: Write to LKML or open a bug report at https://bugzilla.kernel.org

Comment: I think code is correct, but I didn't understand it.